# Printf inside a For Loop

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, return, printf

What will this C code print?

```
for(printf(“1”);!printf(“0”);printf(“2”))
printf(“Sanchin”);
return 0;
```

I was expecting this code to result in an infinite loop but instead nothing was printed.
Should the result of this code be an infinite loop, 1202Sanchin, 10, 0 or even 1?

Comment: Nothing, because of failure to compile. E.g. parts like `!printf(“0”);` with non-standard characters. You might need to use this info to get the post/code look like you intend it to... https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Or to put it differently, please provide a [mre] of the code that you obviously seem able to compile.

Comment: @Rai, 1) change smart quotes `“` into quote marks `"`.  2) Change `return 0;` into `fflush(stdout); return 0;` and report what happens.

Comment: It outputs `10` (`1` then `0`) and does not iterate, because the loop condition `!printf("0")` is false.

Comment: Apologies I just recompiled my code using an online c compiler and it indeed prints '10'.  Thank you all :)

Comment: Remember that `stdout` is buffered. Your code contains no newline output or `fflush` although some OS will do that at program termination.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives. Showing all `#include` directives may be important, as a missing `#include` directive can not only cause compile-time errors, but also run-time errors, for example if the compiler interprets a missing declaration as an implicit declaration and makes a false assumption about the type of a parameter. Also, posting all `#include` directives makes it easier for other people to run your program in order to test it.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop can be confusing, but rewrite the code as a while-loop:

```
printf("1");
while(!printf("0")) {
    printf("Sanchin");
    printf("2");
}
return 0;
```

Then read the manual what is the return value of `printf()`:

> Upon successful return, these functions return the number of
> characters printed (excluding the null byte used to end output to
> strings).

So, depending on the condition of your `stdout`, it may print:

- nothing (e.g. if `stdout` is closed)
- 1 (e.g. if `RLIMIT_FSIZE` is set to 1)
- 10 (with no limits on `stdout`).

Comment: This makes so much sense now. So just for a bit more clarification, printf statements in C return non-zero/false characters which would automatically make it 1, but in this case because of the negation symbol "!" converts  it to 0/false ?

Comment: Also, since 1 will be printed from the initial printf("1"), is the 0 produced after the loop has terminated? Or is it a result of the loop being false?

Comment: @Rai "printf statements in C return non-zero/false characters which would automatically make it 1" --> It depends on what is printed as "The printf function returns the number of characters transmitted, or a negative value if an output
or encoding error occurred."  What do you expected `printf("");` to return?

Answer (score 0):

`printf` returns the number of characters written to the output stream (or a negative value in the event of an error); each of `printf("1")`, `printf("0")`, and `printf("2")` will return `1` on success.  Therefore, you should see the following behavior:

- `printf("1")` is executed and its return value is discarded.  `1` is written to the output stream.
- `printf("0")` is executed and its return value (`1`) is the operand of the logical `!` operator.  `0` is written to the output stream.  Since `!1` is equivalent to `0` (false), the loop exits immediately without executing the loop body.  This means neither `printf( "Sanchin" )` nor `printf( "2" )` are executed.

You're not getting any output because standard output is usually *line-buffered* - nothing gets printed until either:

- the buffer is full; or,
- a newline (`'\n'`) is written to the stream; or,
- the stream is manually flushed with `fflush( stdout )`

To see the output, change your code to:

```
for (printf("1"); !printf("0"); printf("2"))
  printf("Sanchin");
putchar( '\n' );
return 0;
```

The output will be `10`.

Comment: I don't think he is not getting any output... IMHO he is actually getting the `1`, but it is overwritten by the system prompt, as he has not issued a final `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

You should  have provided a complete example showing the problem, and not a snippet of code, as the code below:

```
for(printf(“1”);!printf(“0”);printf(“2”))
printf(“Sanchin”);
return 0;
```

is, almost, equivalent to the following one:

```
    printf("1");
    while (!printf("0")) {
         printf("Sanchin");
         printf("2");
    }
    return 0;  /* return 0 is something that needs more context
                * to know what will happen next */
```

As you see, this should print, at least, the string `1` with no line end.  Next is the test of the loop, which explains as follows:  `Printf()` returns the number of characters printed, assuming no error is issued, the printf would have returned the value 1, and after logical negation by operator `!`, results in a false boolean value, which means the loop body is not executed, so just a `1` with no line end should be printed.

The reason you don't observe anything can be one of several, depending on the environment where you have executed the program, but the most probable reason is that your system prompt overwrote it at program termination.  Just change

```
printf("1");
```

by

```
printf("1\n");  /* add a line end to the output */
```

and most probably you will see the single `1` coming out.